# How do I move RDP Profile Disks to a new location or different collection?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, rdp, remote-desktop-services, rds

I have a RDS deployment (2 server 2012 R2 boxes) with a Session Collection setup that users have been using. There are lots of Profile Disks.

I need to create a new Session Collection and move those profile disks to another location, how can I do this?

I tried copying all the disk to a new location, then deleting and creating a new Session Collection pointing to this new location for the profile disks, but when users logged in they all got temp profiles.

How do you move Profile Disks around like this to backup and or import them(to other collections)?

Comment: Did you use a tool like robocopy that knows how to copy file permissions when you copied the Profile Disks?

Comment: Ah totally forgot about that! How does RDP actually do permissions? When you configure a Session Collection it is suppose to grant the RD Host computer accounts in the Collection full access to the profile folder, but how does it assign user permissions (ie assigning creater owner)? Is there a doc that explains this?